# A very strange problem with search query

Tags: wp-query, search

I have two custom post types. `businesses` `profiles` sharing a single taxonomy `locations`.

When I use WP Query for retrieval of common posts it returns common posts. Here is the query I am using.

```
$queryargs = array(
    'post_type' => 'profile',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ait-locations',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    =>  array( 1071 ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

this query returns two posts. all good till here.

**BUT** when I use the wordpress search to do the same thing it results in no posts found.

**Here** is the URL I am using in the wordpress post

```
?s=&post_type=profile&ait-locations=1071
```

**IF** if on the search page I try `global $wp_query;` and then echo the query that is currently being executed on the search page it returns

```
array(3) {
  ["s"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(7) "profile"
  ["ait-locations"]=>
  string(4) "1071"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, WordPress searches by keyword. To use a custom query variable for search, you would have to register the custom query variable using [**`query_vars`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars)

```
function wpse250276_register_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'ait-locations';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse250276_register_query_vars' );
```

Then you need to use [**`pre_get_posts`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter search query and include your custom taxonomy filter using [**`get_query_var`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

```
function wpse250276_pre_get_posts($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {

        $tax_query = array();
        // add taxonomy query elements
        if( !empty( get_query_var( 'ait-locations' ) ) ){
            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'ait-locations',
                'field'     => 'term_id',
                'terms'     => array( get_query_var( 'city' ) ),
            );

            $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts','wpse250276_pre_get_posts' );
```

Comment: You can pass queries within the search query to filter. checkout
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/build-your-own-custom-wordpress-search/

Comment: I don't think you can pass `tax_query` within the search query filter

Comment: you can I have used it a couple of times..

Comment: doe sthe filter work for you?